# Android: How to enable ellipsize on a TextInputEditText?

Tags: android, material-design

Is there a way to turn on `ellipsize` on a `TextInputEditText` element?

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="asdf asf asf asf sa fdasdf asf asf asf sa fdasdf asf asf asf sa fdasdf asf asf asf sa fdasdf asf asf asf sa fd" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Even if I use `singleLine` and `ellipsize:end` it is still not showing the `...` dots. If I use a `EditText` with `editable:false` it will work but I want to use a `TextInputEditText` and the properties don't work there.

Comment: What are you going to do if you over the width while typing?

Comment: If I'm typing it should behave the normal way: scroll to the curser. Just while viewing it (no focus) it should be in ellipsize mode